# I am trying to create several buttons that each show a different database in MySQL but the database names come out as undefined

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

my main issue is when I try to place each database name on a button. Only one button is displayed and it reads out undefined. The reason I am confused is because in console it lists out all of the databases but when I try to transfer them to buttons I either get [object, Object] or undefined.

---

Here is my code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');

var port = 3000;
const app = express();

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port '+port);
});

//showing databases

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let sql = 'show databases';
    db.query(sql, (err, reply) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(reply);
        res.send(display(reply))
        function display(databases){
            var i = 0;
            while(i < databases.length){
                return('Showing databases...' + '<br> <br>' + '<input type="button" onclick="location.href=\'http://localhost:3000/database/' + databases[i].name + '\';" value="' + databases[i].name + '" />' + '<br>');
                i++;
            }
        }
    });
});

//connection

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password'
});

//connecting

db.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
        return;
    }
    console.log("Connected!");
});

//enter database

app.get('/database/:db', useDatabase);
    
function useDatabase(req, res){
    var data = req.params;
    let sql = 'use ' + data.db;
    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        res.send('Entering ' + data.db + '...' + '<br> <br>' + '<input type="button" onclick="location.href=\'http://localhost:3000/showtables\';" value="Show Tables" />')
    });
    
}

//showing tables

app.get('/showtables', (req, res) => {
    let sql = 'show tables';
    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        res.send('Showing tables...' + '<br> <br>' + result + '<br> <br>' + '<input type="button" onclick="location.href=\'http://localhost:3000/database/project\';" value="Back to Project" />')
    });
});
```

---

When the code runs the console outputs the following:

```js
Server started on port 3000
Connected!
[ RowDataPacket { Database: 'information_schema' },
  RowDataPacket { Database: 'mysql' },
  RowDataPacket { Database: 'nodemysql' },
  RowDataPacket { Database: 'performance_schema' },
  RowDataPacket { Database: 'project' },
  RowDataPacket { Database: 'test' } ]
```

---

When I go and enter "localhost:3000" into my browser it displays

Showing databases...

and it also outputs one button that says undefined.

---

I am trying to have a button for each database that can be clicked on to take the user to the database but it is only displaying the one button that says undefined. I have little to no experience with this and any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my problem was.

In order to call a specific object in the array I just had to put what ever was inside the {} with the object.

Example:

```js
[ RowDataPacket { Database: 'information_schema' },
  RowDataPacket { Database: 'mysql' },
  RowDataPacket { Database: 'nodemysql' },
  RowDataPacket { Database: 'performance_schema' },
  RowDataPacket { Database: 'project' },
  RowDataPacket { Database: 'test' } ]
```

If I wanted to get 'information_schema' out of the above array I just use.

```js
databases[0].Database
```